# Cannot solve syntax errors

Tags: c++, oop, compiler-errors

What is wrong? Tell me please.
Blames for x, syntax and many other.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class point {
    double x;
    double y;

public:
    point(x = 0.0, y = 0.0) : x(x), y(y) {}
    double getx() { return x; }
    double gety() { return y; }
    void setx(double v) { x = v; }
    void sety(double v) { y = v; }
    // private:
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, point& p) {
    out << "( " << p.getx() << ", " << p.gety() << " )";
    return out;
}
point operator+(point& p1, point& p2) {
    point sum = {p1.x + p2.x, p1.y + p2.y};
    return sum;
}

int main() {
    // x = point()  {x=y=1.2;};
}
```

I'll be very thankful for help because I cant really understand what's wrong

Comment: _"Blames for x, syntax and many other."_ isn't much help to us or other uses visiting the Stack Overflow who may have a similar problem. You should include the _exact_ error messages in your post (not in comments).

Comment: All those `getx()`/`setx()` functions don't really add much value and seem rather unnecessary. You would have a much simpler interface by just making `x` and `y` public.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
point(x=0.0, y = 0.0):x(x),y(y){}
```

what type is x? You need to specify it, e.g.

```
point(double x=0.0, double y = 0.0):x(x),y(y){}
```

**Take a look at your compiler's errors, they exist for a reason**

Edit: I'm guessing your next error will be even more traumatic so I'll explain it here: you're also trying to access private stuff in your operator+ free function:

```
point operator+ (point &p1, point &p2){
      point sum = {p1.x + p2.x, p1.y + p2.y}; // x and y are private!
      return sum;
      }
```

since:

```
class point
{     // default here is "private:"
      double x;
      double y;
  public:
      // after this point everything will be public
```

The fix is either to render those public or to make the free function a [friend](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/inheritance/) one. Or better, as Mike noted, use your public interface.

Comment: "The fix is either to render those public or to make the free function a friend one." - or, better still, use the public interface.

Comment: /agree, those setX and getX are purely decorative right now